# how to save photo in album with metadat using PHPhotolibrary in iOS9?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, phphotolibrary

I have  write the following code to save photo in album.  it's work fine in iOS8 but It doesn't work in iOS9.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

        let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(newImage!)

        let assetPlaceholder = assetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset

        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: album, assets: albumFetch)

        albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder!])

        }, completionHandler: { success, error in

            print("added image to album")

            print(error)



    })
```

I got the error

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain"

in iOS9.

Please give me some advice to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you figured out a way?

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested example of how I achieve it:

```
var assetPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let newcreation:PHAssetCreationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAsset()    
        newcreation.addResourceWithType(PHAssetResourceType.Photo, data:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!, options: nil)    
        assetPlaceholder = newcreation.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    } else { // < ios 9
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)    
        assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset     
    }
    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: assetCollection)
    albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
}, completionHandler: {(success:Bool, error:NSError?) in
    print("added image to album")
    print(error)
})
```

I did it this way partly because I needed to use functionality only available in ios 9 but I have removed that from this example.